# Display attachment to mu4e message (a PDF) in the same window rather than new frame

Tags: window, mu4e, gnus, display-buffer

I am using mu4e and pdf-tools. Whenever I go to open an attached pdf (e.g., with `gnus-article-press-button`) the attachment pops open in a new frame. How can I control where it pops up? Looking at that function and trying to trace it I couldn't find anything related to `display-buffer` or something I recognized as window management functionality.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that `gnus-article-press-button` eventually boils down to calling `xdg-open`.

I had `emacsclient` set as my default pdf reader in `mimeapps.list` and using a desktop file that called `emacsclient` with a `--create-frame` argument. Removing the `--create-frames` argument solved the problem and now `emacsclient` tries to use the existing frame when displaying a buffer.